# Adding two arrays in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am fairly new to parallel programming; I am developing a program that deals with numbers in different bases and I want to parallelize the addition method.

Firstly, it computes the linear convolution and does the carrying later, thus every iteration of the for-loop is independent (Example):

```
(Little Endianness btw) [2,7,1] + [8,7,5] = [10,14,6] => [0,5,7]
```

The question is, can I, if there are threads available, make the addition process faster by having the iterations done at the same time in different threads, and how?

Comment: Don't confuse "asynchronous" with "parallel". Asynchronous is freeing up a thread while you wait for some external task to complete (network request, etc.). It's about how your code *waits*. Parallel means running two parts of your code at the same time on multiple threads. It's about how your code *runs*. You want parallel programming.

Comment: Don't confuse "parallel" (which is what multiprocessing hardware offers) with "concurrent" (which is what _threads_ offer - in that different logical executors can maintain independent state permitting them to execute at the same time correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of *huge* arrays (threading has its own overhead), you can try `Parallel`, e.g. [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-6.0):

```
  int[] left  = ...
  int[] right = ...
  int[] result = new int[left.Length];

  ...

  Parallel.For(0, left.Length, i => result[i] = left[i] + right[i]);
```

Let's have a look on the effect:

```
  int N = 100_000_000;

  int[] left   = new int[N];
  int[] right  = new int[N];
  int[] result = new int[left.Length];

  // To prevent garbage collection while testing
  GC.Collect(2);

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();

  // Parallel version
  //Parallel.For(0, left.Length, i => result[i] = left[i] + right[i]);

  // Standard for loop version
  for (int i = left.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    result[i] = left[i] + right[i];

  sw.Stop();

  Console.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Outcome (.Net 6 IA-64, Realease build, Core i9, 6 cores)

```
  200 - parallel version
  500 - for loop version
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have granular work to do, like adding two integers, and you use the [`Parallel.For`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for) method, you'll find that the synchronization overhead, as well as the overhead of invoking a [non-inlinable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529390/do-lambdas-get-inlined) lambda for each index, negates any performance gained by the paralellization. In this case it's a good idea to chunkify the workload by operating on ranges of indices, instead of one index at a time. Here is how you can use the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach)+[`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) methods for this purpose:

```
int[] left = new int[1_000_000];
int[] right = new int[1_000_000];
int[] sum = new int[1_000_000];

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Partitioner<Tuple<int, int>> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, left.Length);
    
Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, parallelOptions, (Tuple<int, int> range) =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        sum[i] = left[i] + right[i];
    }
});
```

The `Partitioner.Create` creates by default about three times as many ranges as the `Environment.ProcessorCount` value, so on a quad core machine it will create about 12 ranges in total. This is a good compromise between too many ranges (overhead) and too few ranges (unbalanced workload). If you want you can finetune the number of the partitions, by configuring the third optional `rangeSize` argument.