# Incorrect number of items in List populated in Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I'm trying to populate a list with a million independently generated items. But after the loop I'm getting less items: 999960, 998534 etc.

As a bypass I've wrapped this code in another that checks generated amount and generates missing items.

I've also tried to sleep after the loop, but it doesn't give a result closer to desired.

```
var someList = new List<ListItem>();
Parallel.For(0, 1000000, _ =>
{
    var item = new ListItem();

    //some logic here

    someList.Add(item);
});

System.Console.WriteLine(someList.Count()); // returns less than 1000000
```

What is the reason of such behaviour and what is the proper way to solve this task?

Comment: `List<T>` is *not* thread-safe. You can try some collection from `System.Collections.Concurrent` or use *Parallel Linq*, e.g. `var someList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000000).AsParallel().Select(_ => new ListItem()).ToList();`

Comment: The term you are looking for is `race condition` and is solved with synchronization, e.g. locking.

Comment: Use system.collections.concurrent for thread safe collections, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this use of Parallel.ForEach() thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605422/is-this-use-of-parallel-foreach-thread-safe)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `//some logic here` contain? That's the most important part. `List` isn't thread-safe and `Parallel.For` isn't meant for asynchronous code, it's meant for data parallelism, ie processing large amounts of in-memory data using all available cores. Adding 1M list items one by one is *very* inefficient and slow, and ends up allocating twice the RAM due to temporary buffers.

Comment: Without information about `//some logic here`, I will advice droping any kind of parrallelism for now.
Or you may be shooting your self in the foot, down the road, by a factor of x2, x4, or even a deadlock, thread starvation. 
And will have to debug a code without the ability to step-in. A code that run way faster, but sometimes doesn't come back. Or come back without finishing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos *"`Parallel.For` isn't meant for asynchronous code"* -- AFAICS the OP is not using the `Parallel.For` with asynchronous lambda.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias check the tags and question ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I removed the `asynchronous` tag. It doesn't seem relevant with the title and body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List<T>` is not thread-safe. You can use a `ConcurrentBag<T>`, although that is an `ICollection<T>`, not an `IList<T>`. If you need the latter then you will have to synchronise the multiple threads, probably using a `lock` statement.

Comment: @EgorShoba you haven't described the problem yet. These are workaround and `lock` is actually a hack when talking about parallelism. Whatever the actual problem is there are better options. Eg if you care about order, `ConcurrentQueue` is a better option. `ConcurrentBag` is a specialized type that uses thread-local storage, offering fast local access but slower cross-thread access. For actual async operations, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is the correct option, not `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: I didn't downvote and don't think this should be downvoted even if it's not the best answer.

Comment: @EgorShoba unless you explain what the problem is, people will downvote this answer because it's not clear why it answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you know how many items you will generate, just use an array:

```
var someList = new ListItem[1000000];
Parallel.For(0, someList.Length, i =>
{
    var item = new ListItem();

    //some logic here

    someList[i] = item;
});
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively you could use the `Parallel.ForEach` with the `Partitioner.Create` as source, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839214/adding-two-arrays-in-parallel/70840104#70840104). It should be slightly more efficient.