# How to implement multithreading in a .NET Core Console application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core

I'm currently working on a .NET Core console application and I came across a scenario where I need to process large amounts of data. To optimize this, I'm thinking about using multithreading.

Here's a simplified version of my current setup:

```cs
public async Task ProcessDataAsync(List<Data> dataList)
{
      foreach (var data in dataList)
      {
          // business logic...
      }
}
```

I've read about the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace and the `Parallel.ForEach` method, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my scenario. Could anyone provide an example of how I could modify my `ProcessData` method to use multithreading?

Also, are there best practices or potential issues I should be aware of when implementing multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It depends. Multi-Threading offers great performance-boosts, but also occupies development and cpu-time to get everything working smooth. Very often adding multi-threading is just an attempt to compensate inefficent code.

Note, that just using async / await is NOT multithreading, it is just "unblocking" the current thread to be able to do something else. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model

As a personal flavour, i'm using (real) threads for background-tasks, and whenever it comes down to adding multi-threading to a workflow that is overall sequential, with just parallel processing possibilities, `Parallel.Foreach()` is quite easy to use and can speed up processing of classic for/foreach loops.

In General, `Parallel.Foreach()` will process items one by one (or say 18 by 18) depending on the degree of parallelism configured. (I always use CPU-Count - 2):

```
List<Something> somethingList;
int availableCores = 20 - 2;

 Parallel.ForEach(somethingList, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = availableCores }, entry => {
    //entry is now a single "Something" item
 }
```

Most the time it is more convinient, if you split an existing list into chunks of equal size - and have 18 parallel executions processing one chunk.

Here is a little extension method (for lists) to achieve that:

```
public enum CollectionChunkStyle
        {
            MAX_LENGTH_PER_CHUNK,
            FIXED_COUNT_OF_CHUNKS
        }

public static List<List<T>> Chunk<T>(this List<T> list, int size, CollectionChunkStyle style)
        {
            List<List<T>> result = new List<List<T>>();
            if (style == Enums.CollectionChunkStyle.MAX_LENGTH_PER_CHUNK)
            {
                List<T> chunk = new List<T>();
                result.Add(chunk);

                int c = 0;
                foreach (T t in list)
                {
                    if (c++ == size)
                    {
                        chunk = new List<T>();
                        result.Add(chunk);
                        c = 1;
                    }

                    chunk.Add(t);
                }
            }

            else if (style == Enums.CollectionChunkStyle.FIXED_COUNT_OF_CHUNKS)
            {
                for (int i=0; i<Math.Min(size, list.Count); i++)
                {
                    result.Add(new List<T>());
                }

                int c = 0;
                foreach (T t in list)
                {
                    result.ElementAt(c++ % size).Add(t);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

It can either be used with `FIXED_COUNT_OF_CHUNKS` - so, say "Split this into 18 lists!" or with `MAX_LENGTH_PER_CHUNK` - saying "Create many chunks, 100 items per chunk please".

Above example then would be as easy as:

```
List<Something> somethingList;
int availableCores = 20 - 2;
List<List<Something>> chunks = somethingList.Chunk(availableCores, CollectionChunkStyle.FIXED_COUNT_OF_CHUNKS);

 Parallel.ForEach(chunks , new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = availableCores }, chunk => {
    //chunk is now a list with 1/18 of somethingLists elements.
 }
```

Comment: The [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) already exists as a LINQ operator (starting from .NET 6). Also the `Parallel.ForEach` already supports partitioning without using the `Chunk` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839214/adding-two-arrays-in-parallel/70840104#70840104 "Adding two arrays in parallel")).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Oh, nice to know - well, using that since years, never checked if there are native alternatives - it's sitting in UseThisDLLEverywhere.dll :P

Answer (score -2):

First, I would move your data process to be a single item on a method:

```
public async Task ProcessDataAsync(Data data)
{
    // business logic...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

That will give you the flexibility to run it how you want.

If you want to run a single task off the main thread:

```
await Task.Run(() => ProcessDataAsync(data));
```

If you want to run all use `Parallel.ForEach` or `Parallel.ForEachAsync`

```
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dataList, ProcessDataAsync);
```